# Having problems getting eslint working in my typescript project

Tags: typescript, cypress, eslint

Here is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.13.0",
    "airbnb": "^0.0.2",
    "cypress": "^9.5.1",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-airbnb": "^0.0.1-security",
    "eslint-plugin-chai-friendly": "^0.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  }
}
```

Here is my `.eslintrc.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:chai-friendly/recommended',
    'plugin:cypress/recommended'
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin',
    'cypress',
    'chai-friendly'
  ],
  rules: {
    'cypress/require-data-selectors': 'warn'
  },
};
```

I'm using VScode, when I save a TypeScript file I'm getting the following error in the output panel:

```
[Error - 9:40:31 AM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/codeAction failed with message: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module '/home/alex/_code/cypress/node_modules/tsutils/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js'
  Code: -32603 
(node:990) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module '/home/alex/_code/cypress/node_modules/tsutils/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js'
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:907:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:15)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:432:14)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:472:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alex/_code/cypress/node_modules/tsutils/index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
(node:990) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 281)
```

Comment: Have you tried installing tslib? e.g.:  `npm i tslib`

Answer (score 1):

retry with `npm i` , after that also the issue is existing then,
let's try to upgrade to the latest version of eslint

Refer to this. https://www.robertcooper.me/using-eslint-and-prettier-in-a-typescript-project

Comment: I rolled back my code to before I installed anything eslint related. So in my package.json file all I had was the two cypress lines and typescript. I deleted my node_modules folder and ran `yarn` to install the dependencies. So I shouldn't have anything eslint related in my project. I then followed the commands in that blog post but I'm still getting the same error message.